# Google Apps script - return multiple text colors

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple custom function on Google Apps script, returning two lines of text:

```
function RPE_MAX() {
  const values = ['one', 'two']
  const first = values[0]
  const second = values[1]
  const formatted = `${first} \n ${second}`
  return formatted
}
```

How can I return the first line in one font color and the second one in another font color?

Comment: If your asking about a spreadsheet cell, use [richTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newRichTextValue())

Comment: You are describing a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). Custom functions can only return values and cannot return cell formats such as font colors. What you are asking cannot be done with a custom function.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). Custom functions can only return values and cannot return cell formats such as font colors. What you are asking cannot be done with a custom function.

Use a regular function like the one Cooper shows, and call it through some other means, such as a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets), a [custom menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus), a [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) or a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

Answer (score 1):

Using RichTextValue:

```
function RPE_MAX() {
  const red = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("red").build();
  const blu = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("blue").build();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const values =[['one', 'two','three','four'],['five','six','seven','eight']]; 
  sh.getRange("A1").setValue(`${values[0].join(' ')}\n${values[1].join(' ')}`);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const txt = sh.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue();
  const v = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText(txt)
    .setTextStyle(0,txt.indexOf('\n'),red)
    .setTextStyle(txt.indexOf('\n')+1, txt.length,blu)
    .build();
    sh.getRange('A1').setRichTextValue(v)
}
```

[image]

This also works if you don't want to get your text from the spreadsheet which is normally what I do.

```
function RPE_MAX() {
  const red = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("red").build();
  const blu = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("blue").build();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const values =[['one', 'two','three','four'],['five','six','seven','eight']]; 
  const txt = `${values[0].join(' ')}\n${values[1].join(' ')}`;
  const v = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText(txt)
    .setTextStyle(0,txt.indexOf('\n'),red)
    .setTextStyle(txt.indexOf('\n')+1, txt.length,blu)
    .build();
    sh.getRange('A1').setRichTextValue(v)
}
```

Comment: The question specifies a custom function context. The code in the answer cannot be run as a custom function.

Comment: [[Custom Functions cannot use set](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced).  So either do it this way or learn to live without it.

Comment: Thank you @Cooper. I'm afraid that, even while your answer shows an alternative to my issue, the question relates a custom function scenario. Would you add the infeasibility for doing this on top of your answer for me to tick it? So other users can have the full explanation.

Comment: The link describes the the restrictions for custom functions